# Build HTTP server for clients to download install package

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, upload

I have a Windows 2012 R2 server in our internal network. I added IIS role according to http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/installing-iis-8-on-windows-server-2012

Where do I find tutorial on how to build simple website where our internal users download installation package, i.e. users should go to

http://internal_server.com/setup.exe

The setup.exe will be stored in the C:\ of the 2012 R2 server

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have set up and configured IIS (link [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323972)) then you will want to set up a simple web page with links to the files you want to download.

1. Create a simple page named index.html in notepad (make sure you change the file type to "all" when saving) and save it in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\
2. copy paste the following:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <body>

   <h1>Your Heading</h1>

   <p>Some text you would like your visitors to see.</p>

   </ br>

   <a href="somedocument.pdf">Click here for your file</a>

   </body>
   </html>'
   ```
3. Change the text "Your Heading", "Some text you would like your visitors to see.", "Click here for your file" to whatever text you would like there.
4. Change `<a href="somedocument.pdf">` to reflect the name of the file you want your users to download...
5. Copy the file you want to users to download to c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ *MAKE SURE YOU COPY IT TO THE SAME DIRECTORY THAT index.html IS IN!!!
6. If you have additional files copy/paste the following (changing the filename as appropriate.) for each file needed.

   ```
   </ br>

   <a href="somedocument.pdf">Click here for your file</a>
   ```

That is all there is to it bro. Good luck.

This is a bit safer than allowing directory browsing.

Comment: It's just one .exe file, hence this is the solution

Answer (score 1):

The root of the website is `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\` - You can create your site there.  IIS also allows you to point a site at another location if preferred, but you'll have to make sure the permissions are correct to allow the pages to be viewed.

Answer (score 1):

I'll describe the steps and avoid any speech about security you should consider.

1. Open IIS
2. Right click your default website -> Add virtual directory
3. Give it an alias and point it to your files directory
4. Click the new virtual directory created -> Directory Browsing (mid panel)
5. On the right panel, Enable Directory Browsing

Should be working and it will keep the directory browsing enabled just for this folder. For example, if your alias is named /files. Just navigate to http://yoursite.com/files. Users will be able to list and download anything on it.

if you get an error 404 while trying to download .exe files make sure you add .exe to the MIME Types. Click Add New -> Type ".exe" (without quotes) under File Name Extension -> In MIME Type type "application/octet-stream".

Comment: I cannot find "Enable Directory Browsing". Using IIS 8. Is there another alternative?